# Clear all deleted data in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to ES, so the question can be somehow stupid, but:

I was experimenting with ES, creating index, putting some data there (1Mio records), and deleting it after and creating the same (with thу same name)
It seems that ES is not actually deleting the data in Index (via curl DELETE) as the disk space is not freed after all the deletes - for now 1Mio records seem to take 40Gb of disk space)

Is there any way to delete the deleted data totally so it will actually free space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its just for experimentation a quick dirty way would be to delete your data directory.

Another way to reclaim disk space is to run this command

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_optimize?only_expunge_deletes=true'
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't help...freed about 1Gb and Marvel still shows DOCUMENT COUNT of 50Mio records but the database size is just 1Mio( I think the problem is that I did the following:
1) create index (lets call it INDEX1)
2) Imported data there
3) Deleted INDEX1 without deleting all the documents inside
4) Recreated INDEX1

So now it seems like all the docs are still stored, but can not be deleted because the index doesn't exist..something like that... I cant figure out how to fix this now..

Comment: Did you try deleting your data directory?

Comment: can you run this command and post the output (or a link to it) in your question? curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_stats?pretty'

Comment: Anfab: Deleting directory is not an option, I'm looking for real solution we can use in future in case it will be the same situation again. It cant be true that the data can not be deleted totally as it can grow the DB size all the time)

Comment: @AndreyPopov looks like you're removed the file, link is dead.